# how to export records/data from one database table to another database table?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

How do you export records from one database table and import it into another database table?
(same table structure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table have the exact same structure, and no autogenerated fields you can use:

```
insert into DestinationTable
  select * from SourceTable
```

You can also use the

```
select * 
  into DestinationTable 
  from SourceTable
```

syntax, to create and fill the destination table on the fly.

Comment: Be warned that the second snippet holds nasty locks on system tables while it's running. Best to use "select top 0 * into ... " to copy the structure but not the data, then use the first statement to actually copy the data.

Comment: I agree. The second form is very usefull for ad-hoc queries on not-too-large tables. For stored code, I would recommend using the first form, with a explicit column list.

Comment: Is there any solution for tables with autogenerated keys (int) and with references?

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to keep you identity colums same you can easily do it using code smith template. Download the templates from [here](http://ScriptTableData.cst) and use ScriptTableData.cst template in them. Before that you will required to install code smith on you machine too.